# How to preface Windows Explorer task bar icons with drive letters?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I'm frequently copying files from 1 server to another, each with identical directory structures- differing just by the drive letter, obviously. Is there a way to make it so that the icons will preface every folder with the drive letter?

It's very confusing looking at 2-5 different windows open all with identical displays as I'm copying from server to server to backup and such.

[image]

So instead of just showing "Central" for both folders, it'd display "Z: ... Central" or "V: ... Central" ?

I've tried searching around for this, but all I can find are "basic" Windows things like changing from grouped / condensed icons to separate icons per instance. I also found something that suggests adding a new key to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer` + `ShowDriveLettersFirst = 4` but that just prepends the drive letters in the sidebar in Windows Explorer, not the tray icons.

Comment: LAME IDEA... Change the folder Icon for the specific folders so they look different on each server? Shitty idea if you need it applied to EVERY folder. This only applies for the folder open, for example if you open a sub folder, the icon would just go back to a folder or whatever it is set to. More of a work around if you only access Central on V: Z: L: and don't navigate to any sub-folders.

Comment: @chrstphrmllr An interesting idea, but yea unfortunately it wouldn't work very well for this situation as they're all test servers for a webapplication so as soon as I start moving stuff around I'm going to need to dig into different subdirectories

Comment: Have you considered mounting that folder with a different name, or using symlinks?

Comment: Explorer also has an option deep in the settings "Display full path in titlebar". This will help with open windows, but not the jumplists.

Comment: @Eris I'm not sure what a "jumplist" is, but this shows the full path in the task bar icons so if you want to post that as an answer I'll accept it. Not *100%* what I was looking for, but it sure beats anything I've found otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explorer has an option deep in the settings called 'Display full path in titlebar'. (Due to the disparities in various windows/explorer versions, I'm omitting the actual instructions to find the setting)

This will make the titlebars in any open windows show the full path. Unfortunately, this doesn't affect the titles shown in the most recently used folders lists.